# Reading 'RAILS_ROOT' variable inside a plugin in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm creating a plugin for my Rails 2.3.8 and inside my plugin's `init.rb` file  I have the following code

```
"#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/myerror.log"
```

I'm trying to create a 'myerror.log' file in log/ folder), but it seems like plugin can't read the `RAILS_ROOT` variable (I'm getting the following error in my plugins unit tests:

```
`const_missing': uninitialized constant RAILS_ROOT (NameError)
```

I did some web-searching but couldn't find an answer. How to run unit tests with in a plugin with 'RAILS_ROOT') variable, or what are the other best practices?

I'm running on Rails 2.3.8 on Linux.

Comment: Hi @taro, thanks for the answer, as far as i know Rails.root is the Rails3 replacement for RAILS_ROOT in rails < 3.x, But here As I mentioned I'm using rails 2.3.8, :D

Answer (score 0):

You should define the RAILS_ROOT constant by using

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), '../../../')
```

Comment: might not be the optimal solution but worked for me but in the path I used '../../' instead of 3 /.